# Merging two objects with a smooth transition

Tags: modeling, rendering, modifiers

[image]

Hi

I want to merge the body and arm objects together so there is a smooth transition between them just like the right side of the image.

[image]

**Wireframe View**

Youtube instructions demonstrate connecting all the vertices one by one.
My question is that if there are more practical and easier ways to achieve this effect such as those involving a specific modifier

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/208837/how-to-make-the-arms-of-a-rigged-character-slide-on-the-surface-of-the-body/208858#208858

Comment: Either boolean union them together and sculpt the joint smooth, or use this technique:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=luFz5gzvM9s
Personally I really like the shrinkwrap technique like in the video!