# How to join two objects with curvy conjunctions

Tags: modeling, rendering

[image]

Here is what I am trying to make.

In the picture, Kirby's arms are connected to the body, but the connected areas are very smooth.

[image]

I am trying to do the same to the joining area in the red circle.

Using union boolean cant make the smaller sphere move around like the first gif as it makes two objects into one

**How can I unify those two spheres with round curvy conjoining areas + allow them to move around like the first gif?**

THank you all always and let me know if you need more info! :)

Comment: hello, maybe try one of these solutions: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/208837/how-to-make-the-arms-of-a-rigged-character-slide-on-the-surface-of-the-body

Comment: what about using metaballs? ;)

Comment: Yes I also thought about that but it has its limitations  ;)

Comment: Thanks all for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use metaballs or sculpt brushes to make it look like the same object. However, I personally prefer metaballs if you are animating them.

Comment: Metaball worked for me too. Thank you for helping! :)